Google Assistant doesn't work in Telegram. Why?
I'm not Telegram developer. I'm only interested in why Google Assistant doesn't work with Telegram even If it has shorcuts.xml?
For example, I'm asking GA "Call to my mom on Telegram" it asks me what app I want to use and there are only two options - Phone and Whatsapp. So, for me looks like GA doesn't detect shortcuts.xml (<capability android:name="actions.intent.CREATE_CALL"> is inside) with from Telegram app. Telegram installed from Google Play.
Tested on Android 10 and 14 with different phones.
I'm just interesting why it happens? Maybe you guys have some ideas because after few weeks of googling didn't find any reason

Assuming that the Telegram app is configured, realize that on https://developer.android.com/develop/devices/assistant/intents it states Google may exercise discretion in surfacing your Action in response to user requests. so what Google Assistant does is at Google's option and may depend on which back-end is being used, i.e. classic Google Assistant or Gemini or whatever is being tested.
